How to access current active profile in a static method?
I have a utility class with a bunch of static methods for updating certificates in the truststore. Within the static method I need to know the name of the current active profile. Since it's static I can't pass the value from @Value("${spring.profiles.active:}"). Is there a better way to do this?
Project is in Java 11 and Springboot 2.7.

Maybe you could use a @Profile annotation to solve this problem?

You could create implementation for each profile with @Profile annotation above the class and provide it to one interface that represents utility class functionalities used in the application.
However I am not sure that it will work with static. Probably should be, but i have never tried it.

Ok so it's a lot less complicated than I thought. I basically just got the value in a spring managed class, then pass that value back to the utility class. Something like this:
@Component
class OuterClass{
  private final Environment env;
  
  @Autowired
  public OuterClass(Environment env) {this.env=env;)
  UtilityMethod.staticMethod(env.getActiveProfiles())
}


You can try to do something like this:
@Component
public class ProfileUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
private static Environment environment;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
}

public static String getActiveProfile() {
    String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
    if (activeProfiles.length > 0) {
        return activeProfiles[0]; // Assuming one active profile
    } else {
        return "default";
    }
}

}
